# Why do I have to source ~/.bash_login every time I open Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

When ever I close and open Terminal.app, it never loads my ~/.bash_profile. I have my RVM setup at the top of the file but it never loads it.

As you can see, when I type `rvm` into Terminal, it says `command not found` this is a pain as I have to run `source ~/.bash_login` every time I open Terminal.

[image: rvm command not found]

Am I the only one with this problem? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does your Terminal preferences window, under the 'Startup' tab look like?

Comment: They show this:  http://i.qyk.in/loD8A.png

Comment: Strange, considering the bash man page:

`When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.  After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.  The --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.` And that /usr/bin/login setting is self-explanatory...

Comment: "it never loads my ~/.bash_profile" "I have to run `source ~/.bash_login`" Which is it? Are you using ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login? Only one of them will be run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it have to be `.bash_login`? Try renaming it to `.profile`.

Comment: Or `.bash_profile` - which works

Comment: This is very surprising. ~/.bash_login should work just as well as ~/.bash_profile. It works for me. You can put an `echo .bash_login` at the start of ~/.bash_login to see whether it gets run. Of course, it won't be run if you also have ~/.bash_profile.

Answer (score 2):

Bash only reads the `.bash_login` file if it's started as a login shell (was passed the `--login` flag). Try renaming it to `.bashrc` instead, which is evaluated when `bash` was invoked as an interactive shell without the `--login` flag.

Comment: I have tried .bashrc but it does the same

Comment: Prior to Lion, Terminal creates login shells unless you provide a custom command in **Preferences > Startup** or **Preferences > Settings > [profile] > Shell**. As of Mac OS X Lion 10.7, Terminal always creates login shells, even for custom commands, if they're listed in /etc/shells.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your .bash_login script doesn't contain relative paths like

source .profile

Change to

source ~/.profile

Lion changes the directory to your current tab or where your last session is, so all paths have to be absolute now.

Answer (score 1):

For me bash in Lion does not load ~/.profile either.

Adding `source ~/.profile` command to run at startup in shell preferences helped, but is quite unelegant.

Comment: Check your preferences to ensure you haven’t done something to suppress the creation of a login shell. Is anything in **Terminal > Preferences > Settings > [profile] > Shell > Startup** or **Terminal > Preferences > Startup > Shells open with** customized?

Answer (score 0):

Changing .bashrc from

```
source .bash_profile
```

to

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

did the trick for me.

Comment: I recommend going the other direction: Have ~/.bash_profile source ~/.bashrc. Put all the stuff you want to be common to login and non-login shells into ~/.bashrc. ~/.bash_profile should only contain configuration commands for login shells.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior on my MacBook running Sierra (I don't know about High Sierra) seems to be that Terminal will run `.bash_profile` on login.

*Only if `.bash_profile` does not exist* will Terminal go and run `.bash_login` instead.

Check to make sure that you do not have an empty `.bash_profile` sitting around in your home directory. If you do, delete it and re-login; then you should see Terminal running your `.bash_login`.

(Empirically: my MacBook does not open or run either `.profile` or `.bashrc`. But indeed, I can disable my `.bash_login` by running `touch ~/.bash_profile`, and restore it to working order by running `rm ~/.bash_profile`.)